# DataBase.Exist() returns true even if the connection string has wrong database name in Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am new to EF 5.0, i have purposely set the wrong database name in connection string in Web.Config. i.e. Initial Catalog = "Wrong Database Name";

Now I have created a boolean property, which detects whether the database exists or not. Like below - where context is the EFDbContext.

```
bool IsDatabaseExist = context.DataBase.Exists();
```

My question is, why this is always showing true, even if the DataBase name which I have provided is wrong ?

Comment: Are you sure the context didn't automatically create the database?

Comment: Hmm, need to check this, Can you detail a little more ? How to check this, or how to force that it doesn't create any database ?

Comment: Look in your SQL Server.  Check EF's database initializer.

Comment: @SLaks Sorry but I am very new to using SQL Server and EF. Also I am using SQL Express.

Answer (score 1):

If you did not provide connection string to the constructor of the DbContext derived class you are not using your connection string. The easiest way to do it is to create a parameterless constructor to in your DbContext derived class that calls DbContext constructor - something like this:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public MyContext() : base("name=connectionStringName")
    { }
    ...
}
```

connectionString name is the name of the connection string from your config file.

If you want to check what connection string your application is using you can do the following:

```
((SqlConnection)myContext.Database.Connection).ConnectionString
```

myContext here is an instance of the DbContext derived class